# installing php-soap in cent0s 6.7 not showing in php-info

Tags: php, apache, soap, centos

I have installed soap php by this command

## yum install php-soap

below is the package information
**Package php-soap-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version**

after that i updated updatedb and located soap.so at location
/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so

i have added extension in file /usr/local/lib/php.ini
extension= "/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so"

after that i restarted apache httpd

## service httpd restart

i cant see soap in php-info.. i double checked everything... i dont know what went wrong..

Comment: Do you use php fpm ? if so, you have to restart it too.

Comment: no im not using php fpm

Comment: i restarted the server... still same

Answer (score 0):

check this in command line:

```
php -i|grep soap
```

if there is :

```
/etc/php.d/soap.ini,
soap
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

then you can use soap in your code.

Comment: php -r '$client     = new SoapClient("http://google.com", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); '   is another way.

Comment: php -i | grep soap ouput is empty :-(

Comment: try this:   `strace php -i 2>&1|grep soap`     and paste result

Comment: open("/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so", O_RDONLY) = 3

Comment: `php -i |grep php.ini ` to check

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini